# Documents uploaded

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-library

I am hoping to create a SharePoint list where team members edit the form, update their details and upload their thesis documents. 
Is there a way in SharePoint, when a team member uploads a document in the form, it auto creates a folder(against their names) in the document library and the document they attach gets housed against their name.
i'm currently using SharePoint 2013.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom web part to handle this. It can be a 2 step activity where in the first step you can save the user details in your list and then on the second step create a new folder in your document library and post the documents. This can be done using SharePoint JavaScript libraries and REST API available in SharePoint 2013.

Please check [this Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints) for details on the API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to handle this using the workflow or event receiver. Develop a list level workflow in the user list... once the save their details in the list.. workflow will get triggered and automatically a folder will be created in the document library with the particular user name... then once they attach any files in the list, those will be copied to document library into their respective user folder - so, workflow is the ideal way to handle this.